# Using MediaController.MediaPlayerControl with Service

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, mediacontroller

I'm using `mediaController` with MediaPlayer which is contained in bound to activity service.
The problem is that when I start playing music, `mediaController` is not updated until I press any button on it. `getCurrentPosition()` returns 0, `getDuration()` returns 2025484024 which displays 562:38:04 as track duration on `mediaController`. It all works fine when I press pause/play button.
Also I've just noticed that when in paused state, `seekTo(i)` is not working. I guess it's connected somehow.

In logs i get error **"MediaPlayer﹕ Attempt to call getDuration without a valid mediaplayer"**.

I think the problem is that I call `setController()` when Service' `mediaPlayer` object is not in Prepared state (I use `prepareAsync()` to prepare `mediaPlayer`).

What is the issue with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

The problem is that I've overriden hide() method so that mediaController will be always visible. During work show() method called only once before mediaPlayer is prepared. The handler which is responsible for updating seekbar and other mediacontroller elements doesn't receive message (which is sent in show() method by default). You can solve this problem by overwriting any method of mediacontroller so that it will sendEmptyMessage(SHOW_PROGRESS) after mediaPlayer is set.